# Shaka-Player start fullscreen

Tags: css, reactjs, fullscreen, video-player, shaka

**Context:**
Currently I'm making a demo project with the intention of finding out if Shaka-Player could be viable option for us in the future.
For the purposes of the project I'm unable to use the standard controls, because we use custom controls.
The project is being developed in Reactjs.

**Question:**
How am I supposed to get the Shaka-Player to start from Fullscreen without using the standard "controls - fullscreen" way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggle fullscreen on shaka player by calling `.requestFullscreen()` on the video element.

*Side note since you mentioned you are using custom controls:

[According to this issue](https://github.com/google/shaka-player/issues/1566), fullscreening a video element in Chrome forces the browser-native video controls. The suggested workaround for this issue is to fullscreen the element that contains your video element and controls.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar project and this way works for me

1. You should build shaka player without the ui to avoid not needed code in your application
2. You can get the shaka player state with events and map it to your react components
3. you should use requestFullscreen on player and controls container. It works good on all modern browsers

The only problem is Firefox **Picture In Picture** feature. Browser will move video element to right-bottom corner without the UI.